# Why could "update database" be missing in visual studio 2012 when publishing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, one-click-web-publishing

I'm trying to deploy an application to my webserver and everything works, except that it does not update the remote database.

With a new demo MVC project you have the option "Update database" when publishing 
For some reason that options is not available when I want to publish my own MVC project.

Why is this option not showing?

- I am using EF (database first)
- I am getting a warning under the connectionstring fields: in order to publish a code first model you must enable EF code first migrations. (*although this project should not use code first*)
- Web Deploy 3.0 and the dbDacFx provider are installed on the server

-- EDIT --
I have now recreated the project, and the update database keeps showing *until the first web publish*. then it just disappears and shows the warning *in order to publish a code first model you must enable EF code first migrations*. (although im not using code first, im using database first) Is this a bug in VS or what am I doing wrong?

--FIX--
I got it working by adding another connection string pointing to my database (without EF interference) in web.config: `<add name="DeployCode" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`